# Validating the existence of an image without making it required with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

**Background:**

I have a database which stores information about items.I am currently using a form that dynamically extracts and displays the current existing data about any item in the database, and changes to the form are updated in the database.

My form has a field (ImagePreviewDP) which shows a picture(Display pic) of the item currently being shown.I am trying to validate this picture to make sure that it exists and make it a required field, and that if the display pic is deleted, the form cannot be submitted without uploading a new display pic to replace the deleted one. ImagePreviewDP is 
currently set to automatically display the existing display pic upon page load, and to show the picture selected via the file input field.
**Problem:**

My display pic's validation is **NOT WORKING** at the moment, as users are able to delete the display pic and submit the form.

Php Code to generate the form(extract):

```
//Fetches the item DP
$fetchdp=$cxn->prepare("SELECT `ItemDP` FROM `Items` WHERE `BusinessID`=:bizid AND `ItemID`=:itemid");
$fetchdp->bindValue(":bizid",$bizid);
$fetchdp->bindValue(":itemid",$itemid);
$fetchdp->execute();
while($getdp=$fetchdp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $dp=$getdp["ItemDP"];
}

//Input and preview for Display Pic
echo"<div class='BizEditItemDetails' >";
    echo"<label for='BizEditItemFileDP'>Upload Image[DP] &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp(Max Size:2MB)</label>";
    echo"<input type='file' class='BizEditItemInput' id='BizEditItemFileDP' name='BizEditItemFilesDP' />";
    echo"<input type='button' id=ImageCancelDP name=ImageCancelDP class='ImageCancelButton' value='Cancel'>";
    echo"<span></span>";
    echo"<br>";
    echo"<img id=ImagePreviewDP name=ImagePreviewDP class='ImagePreview' src=".$dp." > ";
    echo"<input type='hidden' id=DisplayDeleteItemID name=DisplayDeleteItemID value=$itemid>";
    echo"<input type='hidden' id=DisplayDeleteItemPicID name=DisplayDeleteItemPicID value=$itempicid>";
    echo"<input type='hidden' id=DisplayDeleteFilePath name=DisplayDeleteFilePath value=$dp >";
    echo"<input type='button' id=DisplayDelete name=DisplayDelete class='ImageDeleteButton' value='Delete Picture'>";
    echo"<br>";
echo"</div>";
```

jQuery validate rules(extract):

```
'BizEditItemFilesDP':{
    remote:{
    url:"checkdp.php",
    type:"get",
    data:{dp:$("#ImagePreviewDP").prop("src")}
    }
},
```

Code for remote call:

```
require("../../inc/connection.inc");

$dp=$_GET['dp'];
$check=$cxn->prepare("SELECT `ItemDP` FROM `Items` WHERE `ItemDP`=:dp")
$check->bindValue(":dp",$dp);
$check->execute();
$count=$check->rowCount();

if($count > 0)
{
    echo json_encode(false);
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(true);
}
```

Things tried:

I've tried setting the jQuery validate rules to

```
'BizEditItemFilesDP':{
    required:true,
    remote:{
    url:"checkdp.php",
    type:"get",
    data:{dp:$("#ImagePreviewDP").prop("src")}
    }
},
```

and

```
'BizEditItemFilesDP':{

    remote:{
    url:"checkdp.php",
    type:"get",
    data:function(){
    return $("#ImagePreviewDP").prop("src");
    }
},
```

but it does not work, as the required rule needs a file to be chosen,(selected for uploading), and does not care if there is already an existing file being displayed in the ImagePreviewDP field.

How can i validate the display pic to make it a required field?I've been stuck on this for ages and can't seem to make it work.

Any inputs would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: FIRST change from src=$dp to `src="$dp"`, enclose src attribute in quotes

Comment: @Nouphal.M Hi Noupal, thanks for taking the time to answer, i've already changed it to src="$dp", though it doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: attrib quotes are optional if the attrib value has no space or equals...

Answer (score 0):

This is ok

```
'BizEditItemFilesDP':{
    required:true,
    remote:{
    url:"checkdp.php",
    type:"get",
    data:{dp:$("#ImagePreviewDP").prop("src")}
    }
},
```

But The reason that a file always needs to be chosen is because of the required:true, line in your validation rule.  This will always fail if BizEditItemFilesDP is empty..

also If you want the input to be **valid** when a ImagePreviewDP already exists, it appears that you should be returning true if($count > 0) in your remote validation. (currently you return false).

---

(Seems to be a bit of a catch 22) The issue with validating the way you want to do it is  if required = **true** for BizEditItemFilesDP then leaving it blank immediately fails

BUT

if required = **false** for BizEditItemFilesDP then leaving it blank immediately succeeds (and your remote validation script to check ImagePreviewDP is never called).

A way around it could be to put your validation rule on something that always has a value (a submit button or hidden field or whatever), set required to true for that field in the validation rules, and then send both BizEditItemFilesDP and ImagePreviewDP to your remote validation script and validate them both remotely.  then your remote validation script would always get called.

I'm thinking there must be an easier way to make sure that your remote validation script gets called when BizEditItemFilesDP is not required and is left blank, but i sure couldn't find it.